# Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set() without using set anywhere in the code

Tags: ember.js, breeze

I am using breeze js as my database layer. I am able to add new record and save it to the database. I am getting the following error "Assertion Failed: You must use Ember.set()" when i try to save the data. the data gets saved but my success callback does not fired. Just calling manager.saveChanges() will trigger the error message. The strangest part is i am not using "set" anywhere in my code.

```
App.AddRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    deactivate: function () {
        manager.rejectChanges();
    },
    model: function () {
        return manager.createEntity('OSIPI_ChangeRequest_Input');
    }
});

App.AddController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    init: function () {
        manager.saveChanges();
    },
    actions: {
        validate: function () {
            $('#btn-submit').trigger('click');
        },
        submit: function () {
            var self = this;
            if (manager.hasChanges()) {
                manager.saveChanges().then(function () {

                }).fail(function (msg) {

                });
            };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Breeze doesn't have a modelLibrary adapter to work with Ember yet - please go here to vote on it as I think it would be an awesome feature! https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-1-breezejs-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4275794-plugin-for-ember-js   Without a proper adapter it *will* not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out.

Breeze js is still tracking the changes. I just need to reset the ember model by using the
this.set('content',null) before executing the manager.saveChanges();

Everything is working as I wanted to.

Comment: **VERY curious how you are making this work with Ember** as we haven't developed a modelLibrary adapter for it yet.

Comment: ember can bind to javascript object. so in the route i just return javascript object using breeze js. once i bind it on the form the changes are tracked by breeze.